# WPF ShowDialog again/several times

Tags: wpf

i´ve got an WPF application with an "settings-winwow". if i´m clicking on "info" on the mainwindow, settings.showDialog(); is called - so far so good. It opens and i can do some stuff, bus when i´m closing it and try to open it again, it gives me an error. its called:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> HResult=0x80131509
>
> message = Visibility cant be shown or defined, ShowDialog or
>   WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle cant be called, after the window was
>   closed.

i found this:

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

here on SO, but i doesn´t work or maybe i´m using it the wrong way.. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Don't reuse the `settings` instance. Create a new one.

Comment: Error message is pretty explicit. I don't see what else we can tell you. Documentation is also very clear and what it does (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog) maybe start by reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse the window you should consider to use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`. `ShowDialog` will destroy the object when you close the window. Using `Show' won't block the calling main window. This may be undesirable in your case.

The codes snipped you posted will prevent the destruction of your object by hiding the window instead of closing it. If you want to use you snipped, the copy it to your window.

Your XAML code:

```
Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.DialogWindow"
    ...
    Closing="Window_Closing">
```

The C# code in code behind:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

or use `Show` instead like this:

```
DialogWindow.Show();
```

Comment: ah okay, so now i´ve got an other error: it does never close the window, so yes in backend it does, but if the settings once is opened, it s allweis "hidden open"

Comment: Under what conditions you want to close the window and under what condition you want to recycle the window? You can define that conditions in `Window_Closing` and either set `e.Cancle=true` or not.
Anyway it is often better not to use the 'hiding workaround' in many cases it is better to create a new object when ever you want to show the window.

Answer (score 3):

You can only call ShowDialog once on the window. For the next call you need to create a new window.

So the code when clicking on the 'info ' should be:

```
settings = new SettingsWindow();
settings.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: ah okay, so now i´ve got an other error: it does never close the window, so yes in backend it does, but if the settings once is opened, it s allweis "hidden open"

Comment: I'm guessing because of the code in the Window_Closing method, if you remove this it should close completely.

Answer (score 1):

## You can call several times `Window.ShowDialog()`

But you should **never** call `Close()` method 
(until you don't want to use the control anymore: `Close` is like `Dispose` for controls).

Instead you can use `Hide()`.

Then the next call to `ShowDialog()` should work as a `Show()` call.

When the dialog is hidden, other windows and other dialogs should continue to work as usual.

Transform `Close()` calls to `Hide()`

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```